# How I can print with brother printer using react native

Tags: objective-c, react-native, printing

I am using iOS and I am trying to print an image or a file with the library react-native-brother-printers with this example https://github.com/Avery246813579/react-native-brother-printers/tree/master/example

I have the PT-P950NW model (thermal printer).

Does any one do that or have any idea to do that ?

This is my code in app.js

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    printer: "PT-P950NW",
    ip: "192.168.10.232",
  };


 render() {
    const {printer, ip} = this.state;

    return (
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ViewShot ref={(e) => {
          this.viewShot = e;
        }} options={{format: "jpg", quality: 0.9}}>

          <Text style={{fontSize: 24}}>
           // printer test
          </Text>
        </ViewShot>

        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>
            Test Connection
          </Text>

          <Button title="Discover Readers" onPress={() => {
            discoverPrinters().then(() => {
              console.log("Discover Readers Successful");
            }).catch(() => {
              console.log("Discover Readers failed")
            });
          }}/>

          {printer && (
            <Button title="Print from Memory" onPress={() => {
              this.viewShot.capture().then(uri => {
                console.log("do something with ", './icon.png');

                printImage(
                  {
                ipAddress: "192.168.10.232",
                modelName: "PT-P950NW"
                }, uri, {autoCut: false}).then(() => {
                  console.log("Discover Memory Successful");
                }).catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err);
                  console.log("Discover Memory failed");
                });
              });
            }}/>
          )}


          <Button title="Print from Manual" onPress={() => {
            this.viewShot.capture().then(uri => {
              console.log("do something with ", uri);

              printImage({
                ipAddress: "192.168.10.232",
                modelName: "PT-P950NW"
                }, uri, {autoCut: false}).then(() => {
                console.log("Discover Manual Successful");
              }).catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err);
                console.log("Discover Manual failed")
              });
            });
          }}/>

          <TextInput placeholder="Ip Address" value={ip} onChangeText={(ip) => this.setState({ip})}/>

          <Button title="Test Printer" onPress={() => {
            pingPrinter(ip).then(() => {
               //}).then(() => {
            // alert("We found the printer");
              console.log("We found the printer");
        console.log("Printer accessed");
            })catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err);
              console.log("Printer could not be accessed");

              console.log("Printer is dead", err);
            });
          }}/>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

and the index.js of the library

// main index.js

```
import {NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter} from "react-native";

const {ReactNativeBrotherPrinters} = NativeModules;

const {
  discoverPrinters: _discoverPrinters,
  pingPrinter: _pingPrinter,
  printImage: _printImage,
  printPDF: _printPDF,
} = ReactNativeBrotherPrinters;

/**
 * Starts the discovery process for brother printers
 *
 * @param params
 * @param params.V6             If we should searching using IP v6.
 * @param params.printerName    If we should name the printer something specific.
 *
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
export async function discoverPrinters(params = {}) {
  return _discoverPrinters(params);
}

/**
 * Checks if a reader is discoverable
 *
 * @param ip
 *
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
export async function pingPrinter(ip) {
  return _pingPrinter(ip);
}

/**
 * Prints an image
 *
 * @param device                  Device object
 * @param uri                     URI of image wanting to be printed
 * @param params
 * @param params.autoCut          Boolean if the printer should auto cut the receipt/label
 *
 * @return {Promise<*>}
 */
export async function printImage(device, uri, params = {}) {
  return _printImage(device, uri, params);
}

// export async function printPDF(device, uri, params = {}) {
//   return _printPDF(device, uri, params);
// }

const listeners = new NativeEventEmitter(ReactNativeBrotherPrinters);

export function registerBrotherListener(key, method) {
  return listeners.addListener(key, method);
}
```

and this is the code in ReactNativeBrotherPrinters.m file in Objective-c.

```
// ReactNativeBrotherPrinters.m

#import "ReactNativeBrotherPrinters.h"
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>

@implementation ReactNativeBrotherPrinters

NSString *const DISCOVER_READERS_ERROR = @"DISCOVER_READERS_ERROR";
NSString *const DISCOVER_READER_ERROR = @"DISCOVER_READER_ERROR";
NSString *const PRINT_ERROR = @"PRINT_ERROR";

- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
    return dispatch_get_main_queue();
}

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

-(void)startObserving {
    hasListeners = YES;
}

-(void)stopObserving {
    hasListeners = NO;
}

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents {
    return @[
        @"onBrotherLog",

        @"onDiscoverPrinters",
    ];
}

RCT_REMAP_METHOD(discoverPrinters, discoverOptions:(NSDictionary *)options resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    NSLog(@"Called the function");

    _brotherDeviceList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    _networkManager = [[BRPtouchNetworkManager alloc] init];
    _networkManager.delegate = self;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PrinterList" ofType:@"plist"];

    if (path) {
        NSDictionary *printerDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSArray *printerList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:printerDict.allKeys];

        [_networkManager setPrinterNames:printerList];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Could not find PrinterList.plist");
    }

    //    Start printer search
    int response = [_networkManager startSearch: 5.0];

    if (response == RET_TRUE) {
        resolve(Nil);
    } else {
        reject(DISCOVER_READERS_ERROR, @"A problem occured when trying to execute discoverPrinters", Nil);
    }
}

RCT_REMAP_METHOD(pingPrinter, printerAddress:(NSString *)ip resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    BRLMChannel *channel = [[BRLMChannel alloc] initWithWifiIPAddress:ip];

    BRLMPrinterDriverGenerateResult *driverGenerateResult = [BRLMPrinterDriverGenerator openChannel:channel];
    if (driverGenerateResult.error.code != BRLMOpenChannelErrorCodeNoError ||
        driverGenerateResult.driver == nil) {
        
        NSLog(@"%@", @(driverGenerateResult.error.code));
        
        return reject(DISCOVER_READER_ERROR, @"A problem occured when trying to execute discoverPrinters", Nil);
    }

    NSLog(@"We were able to discover a printer");
    
    resolve(Nil);
}

RCT_REMAP_METHOD(printImage, deviceInfo:(NSDictionary *)device printerUri: (NSString *)imageStr printImageOptions:(NSDictionary *)options resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    NSLog(@"Called the printImage function");
    BRPtouchDeviceInfo *deviceInfo = [self deserializeDeviceInfo:device];

    BRLMChannel *channel = [[BRLMChannel alloc] initWithWifiIPAddress:deviceInfo.strIPAddress];

    BRLMPrinterDriverGenerateResult *driverGenerateResult = [BRLMPrinterDriverGenerator openChannel:channel];
    if (driverGenerateResult.error.code != BRLMOpenChannelErrorCodeNoError ||
        driverGenerateResult.driver == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", @(driverGenerateResult.error.code));
        return;
    }

    NSString * paperSize = [self defaultPaperSize:deviceInfo.strModelName];
    NSLog(@"Paper Size: %@", paperSize);

    BRLMPrinterDriver *printerDriver = driverGenerateResult.driver;

    BRLMPrinterModel model = [BRLMPrinterClassifier transferEnumFromString:deviceInfo.strModelName];
    // BRLMQLPrintSettings *qlSettings = [[BRLMQLPrintSettings alloc] initDefaultPrintSettingsWithPrinterModel:model];
    BRLMPTPrintSettings *ptSettings = [[BRLMPTPrintSettings alloc] initDefaultPrintSettingsWithPrinterModel:model];

    // BRLMPTPrintSettings *ptSettings = [[BRLMPTPrintSettings alloc] initDefaultPrintSettingsWithPrinterModel:BRLMPrinterModelPT_P950NW];


    ptSettings.autoCut = true;
    
    NSLog(@"Cut Options %@", options[@"autoCut"]);
    if (options[@"autoCut"]) {
        ptSettings.autoCut = [options[@"autoCut"] boolValue];
    }

      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageStr];
    
  

    BRLMPrintError *printError = [printerDriver printImageWithURL:url settings:ptSettings];
    
    if (printError.code != BRLMPrintErrorCodeNoError) {
         NSLog(@"Error - Print Image: %@", printError); 
         // NSLog(@"Error - Print Image: %@", @(printError.code)); 
        
        NSError* error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.react-native-brother-printers.rn" code:1 userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:printError.description forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]];

        reject(PRINT_ERROR, @"There was an error trying to print the image", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success - Print Image");
        
        resolve(Nil);
    }

    [printerDriver closeChannel];
}

-(void)didFinishSearch:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishedSearch");

    //  get BRPtouchNetworkInfo Class list
    [_brotherDeviceList removeAllObjects];
    _brotherDeviceList = (NSMutableArray*)[_networkManager getPrinterNetInfo];

    NSLog(@"_brotherDeviceList [%@]",_brotherDeviceList);

    NSMutableArray *_serializedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:_brotherDeviceList.count];

    for (BRPtouchDeviceInfo *deviceInfo in _brotherDeviceList) {
        [_serializedArray addObject:[self serializeDeviceInfo:deviceInfo]];

        NSLog(@"Model: %@, IP Address: %@", deviceInfo.strModelName, deviceInfo.strIPAddress);
        // NSLog(@"IP Address: %@",deviceInfo.strIPAddress);

    }

    [self sendEventWithName:@"onDiscoverPrinters" body:_serializedArray];

    return;
}

- (NSString *)defaultPaperSize: (NSString *) printer
{
    NSString *result = nil;

    NSString *pathInPrintSettings   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PrinterList" ofType:@"plist"];
    if (pathInPrintSettings) {
        NSDictionary *priterListArray = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathInPrintSettings];
        if (priterListArray) {
            result = [[[priterListArray objectForKey:printer] objectForKey:@"PaperSize"] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

- (NSDictionary *) serializeDeviceInfo:(BRPtouchDeviceInfo *)device {
    return @{
        @"ipAddress": device.strIPAddress,
        @"location": device.strLocation,
        @"modelName": device.strModelName,
        @"printerName": device.strPrinterName,
        @"serialNumber": device.strSerialNumber,
        @"nodeName": device.strNodeName,
        @"macAddress": device.strMACAddress,
    };
}

- (BRPtouchDeviceInfo *) deserializeDeviceInfo:(NSDictionary *)device {
    BRPtouchDeviceInfo *deviceInfo = [[BRPtouchDeviceInfo alloc] init];

//    return @{
//        @"ipAddress": device.strIPAddress,
//        @"location": device.strLocation,
//        @"modelName": device.strModelName,
//        @"printerName": device.strPrinterName,
//        @"serialNumber": device.strSerialNumber,
//        @"nodeName": device.strNodeName,
//        @"macAddress": device.strMACAddress,
//    };
//
//
    deviceInfo.strIPAddress = [RCTConvert NSString:device[@"ipAddress"]];
    deviceInfo.strLocation = [RCTConvert NSString:device[@"location"]];
    deviceInfo.strModelName = [RCTConvert NSString:device[@"modelName"]];
    deviceInfo.strPrinterName = [RCTConvert NSString:device[@"printerName"]];
    deviceInfo.strSerialNumber = [RCTConvert NSString:device[@"serialNumber"]];
    deviceInfo.strNodeName = [RCTConvert NSString:device[@"nodeName"]];
    deviceInfo.strMACAddress = [RCTConvert NSString:device[@"macAddress"]];

    NSLog(@"We got here");

    return deviceInfo;
}

@end
```

If a use the pingPrinter function and I put the ip of the printer I get :
Discover Readers Successful
LOG  We found these listeners [{"ipAddress": "169.254.33.242", "location": "", "macAddress": "00:80:77:57:83:df", "modelName": "Brother PT-P950NW", "nodeName": "BRN0080775783DF", "printerName": "Brother PT-P950NW", "serialNumber": "E6Z987778"}]

But if a use PrintImage  function I get : There was an error trying to print the image,
this error is in Objective-c file ReactNativeBrotherPrinters.m (https://github.com/Avery246813579/react-native-brother-printers/blob/master/ios/ReactNativeBrotherPrinters.m) in this condition :

```
if (printError.code != BRLMPrintErrorCodeNoError) {
     NSLog(@"Error - Print Image: %@", printError); 
    
    NSError* error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.react-native-brother-printers.rn" code:1 userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:printError.description forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]];

    reject(PRINT_ERROR, @"There was an error trying to print the image", error);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Success - Print Image");
    
    resolve(Nil);
}
```

Also if try to change the url like that:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"./Resources/icon" withExtension:@"png"];
```

I get this error message:

Error - Print Image: setLabelSizeError

and if add this line to specify the size like that:

ptSettings.labelSize = BRLMMWPrintSettingsPaperSizeA7;

I get also another error message:
Error - Print Image: FilePathURLError

those error messages are in this log:

NSLog(@"Error - Print Image: %@", printError);

So what I should do to correct those errors ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi there, can you add what happens when it's not working?

Comment: If I try to print I get the message for catch bloc : console.log("Discover Manual failed"), so I don't have any information about what is wrong in my code

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken, that is enough or you need more ?

Comment: That should help someone to answer or know what's going on, unfortunately cannot help myself with the answer

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken, I just got help from a friend, The error of catch block is "There was an error trying to print the image", this error is at the ligne 120 of the file ReactNativeBrotherPrinters.m (https://github.com/Avery246813579/react-native-brother-printers/blob/master/ios/ReactNativeBrotherPrinters.m)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it, the library react-native-brother-printers work awesome.

Just this library is for the QL series, and if someone has another printer module he should for instance edit the Objective.c file (ReactNativeBrotherPrinters.m) if his choice was Objective-C language and after he can patch the modification of the library with a patch file for example, before not copy paste the modifications in each project.

Because in the Brother Print SDK Manual (https://support.brother.com/g/s/es/htmldoc/mobilesdk/guide/print-image.html), they offer an example for each series.

And if someone has an error message for example SetLabelSizeError he should return in the Manual (https://support.brother.com/g/s/es/htmldoc/mobilesdk/reference/ios_v4/brlmptprintsettings.html#labelsize) and search the setting of his printer, in my case it is BRLMPTPrintSettingsLabelSize.

Comment: I have tried "react-native-brother-printers" this npm as per your answer but getting error in "RNBrotherPrinter.m". Error : BRPtouchPrinterKit/BRPtouchPrinterKit.h' file not found. Any idea about this error like how to resolved make it workable ?

Comment: Can you show your code please ? and which Brother Printer you use  ? You can try directly this example: ``` https://github.com/Avery246813579/react-native-brother-printers/tree/master/example ```